# Can I extend parent's class list attribute on class level?

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance

Suppose, I have the following parent class:

```
class Parent:
    permissions = ['CanEdit', 'CanCreate']
```

I need to extend `permissions` attribute in my child class without changing the initial contents and so that this change would be on the class level, not instance, meaning:

```
print(Parent.permissions)
```

Output:

```
['CanEdit', 'CanCreate']
```

And I need the something like this in my child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    permissions += ['CanManage']
        

print(Child.permissions)
```

With the output:

```
['CanEdit', 'CanCreate', 'CanManage']
```

Is this even possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `permissions = Parent.permissions + ['CanManage']`.